# Excel VBA looping Help Needed

Tags: excel, vba

I need this macro to automatically grab the data from column A, find the data into the path given and replace it with column B. It is working but I need it to work just for once and goes on forward automatically..
Can anyone help me in this..

```
Sub UnkownFunctionName()
    Dim myfolder
    Dim Fnd As String, Rplc As String

    Fnd = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Find string:", Title:="Rename files and folders", Type:=2)
    Rplc = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Replace with:", Title:="Rename files and folders", Type:=2)

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    Call Recursive(myfolder, Fnd, Rplc)

End Sub

Sub Recursive(FolderPath As Variant, Fnd As String, Rplc As String)

    Dim Value As String, Folders() As String, Fname As String, Fext As String, Mtxt As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Folder As Variant, a As Long

    ReDim Folders(0)

    If Right(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then Exit Sub

    Value = Dir(FolderPath, &H1F)

    Do Until Value = ""
        If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
        Else
            If GetAttr(FolderPath & Value) = 16 Or GetAttr(FolderPath & Value) = 48 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Mtxt = "Rename folder " & Value & " to " & WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Value, Fnd, Rplc) & "?"
                x = MsgBox(Mtxt, vbYesNoCancel)

                If x = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
                If x = vbYes Then
                    Name FolderPath & Value As FolderPath & WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Value, Fnd, Rplc)
                End If

                Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Value, Fnd, Rplc)

                If Err <> 0 Then
                    MsgBox "Error"
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                On Error GoTo 0

                Folders(UBound(Folders)) = Value

                ReDim Preserve Folders(UBound(Folders) + 1)
            Else
                On Error Resume Next

                Fext = Split(Value, ".")(UBound(Split(Value, ".")))
                Fname = Left(Value, Len(Value) - Len(Split(Value, ".")(UBound(Split(Value, ".")))) - 1)
                Fname = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Fname, Fnd, Rplc)

                If Value <> (Fname & "." & Fext) Then
                    Mtxt = "Rename file " & Value & " to " & Fname & "." & Fext & "?"
                    x = MsgBox(Mtxt, vbYesNoCancel)

                    If x = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
                    If x = vbYes Then
                        Name FolderPath & Value As FolderPath & Fname & "."& Fext
                    End If
                End If

                If Err <> 0 Then
                    MsgBox "Error"
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If

        Value = Dir

    Loop

    For Each Folder In Folders
        Call Recursive(FolderPath & Folder & "\", Fnd, Rplc)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If this accomplishes what you want, why not put a pause of some kind after the loop that accomplishes your goal completes. For instance-

```
...
End If
If MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
...
```

I'm having a hard time linking what the code does to what your question suggests. It seems that the code renames files and folders. Can you explain a bit more about your goal?

Comment: I would like to Rename the files/folders at once. I actually don't need any pause regarding the procedure. I need to start and end the macro procedure with one press only.

I would like to replace the B Column data by finding the A column's data in the desired path.